# can we have native ads in ionic(angular)?

Tags: ionic-framework, admob, ionic4, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

Is there any possible way I can show native ads(Admob/Facebook) in my ionic 5 app. if that is not possible is there any way to implement ads inside app content. My app is a content-based app and I don't want to use banners and interstitial ads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is the answer.

Take a look at the host of native plugins available here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native

Although not Admob, there is a Facebook ads Cordova plugin which seemingly supports native ads: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-facebookads

It hasn't been updated in 4 years though so not sure how current it is.

Comment: All of them are either banner or Interstitial , i am looking for native ads.

Comment: I've added a bit more to include another Github repo which apparently offers native Facebook ads.

Comment: thanks for the update Simon but it Cordova-plugin-facebook ads plugin is also not working...I am wondering if there is any ad network that offers ads via API call, and we can insert ads in webview using that api.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, the repo did look quite old so wasn't sure if it was still functional.